# Searching for a sub-string inside of string with dashes

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I'm trying to search for a partial string in my array using preg_match. I've got it working well enough, but some of the strings in my array have dashes (-) in them and the results aren't coming back as they should. I'm not too familiar with regex to know why.

Here is my preg_match:

```
if(preg_match("/\b$game\b/i", $value['name']))
{
    var_dump($value['name']);
}
```

If I search for "My Dog", it will give me all the results with the text "My" and "Dog". But any results which have "My-Dog" in them, it won't return them. Is it possible for me also display results if I type "mydog"?

Thanks.

Comment: show the input `$value['name']` value and `$game` value i. e. input and expected output

Comment: I have given both, perhaps I wasn't being clear enough, my bad!

$value['name'] is a the name of a game, so for example: Counter-Strike.


With $game, if I type Counter-Strike in to the input field, it returns correctly. But if I type, counter strike, or counterstrike it returns nothing, and I assume it's because of my pattern?

Comment: Remove `\b` if you do not need word boundaries.

Comment: Even with the `\b` removed I get nothing.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find a match in `counter-strike` string with a `/counterstrike/` regex? Sorry, that is impossible.

Comment: Maybe you should use the [levenstein distance](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.levenshtein.php) to do what you want

Comment: That was one of the aims, yes, but okay, I can work around that. Is it possible to find the match `counter-strike` while searching with `counter strike` (so no hyphen)

Comment: @Cloud: If you want to tell the regex engine to match any character other than word one between `counter` and `strike`, you need to use `/counter\Wstrike/` pattern. A space itself cannot match a hyphen. If you want to explicitly match a space or hyphen, use `[ -]`, i.e. `/counter[ -]strike/`.

Comment: Can you use that pattern if you use a variable?

Comment: What pattern? You may always build a pattern with variables. E.g. `'~\b' . $var . '\b~'`.

Comment: @Cloud Were either of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a function to **standardize** both the test string and the regex string before checking for the match.

```
function standardize($word){
    $word = strtolower($word);
    $word = str_replace("-", "", $word);
    $word = str_replace(" ", "", $word);
    return $word;
}

$game = standardize($game);

if(preg_match("/\b$game\b/i", standardize($value['name'])))
{
    var_dump($value['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this regex pattern:

```
/my[- ]{0,1}dog/i
```

this will search for 'my' then - or empty space, zero or one time and then dog. The i at the end means case insensitive match.